# Are there natural functions which map vectors to scalars, other than length and the dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Where $V$ is an n-dimensional real vector space, the length function maps $V \to \mathbb{R}$ and the dot product maps $V\times V \to \mathbb{R}$.

Are there any other naturally-occuring functions which map some number of vectors in $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

(Something like the scalar triple product wouldn't count because it's not fundamental, it's expressed in terms of dot and cross products.)

Comment: I would guess the map $\Phi(x,y)=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3-x_4y_4$ is a very natural one.

Comment: I don’t think “natural” is a meaningful word in this context (or any context at all for that matter). You could change it to “useful” of “widespread”

Comment: Scalar triple product *can* be expressed in terms of dot and cross products, but it is much more fundamental itself - it's just the determinant.

Comment: A covariant $(0,n)$ tensor $T_{i_1i_2\dotsi_n}$ represents a basis-independent map that maps $n$ vectors to a scalar. Is that what you are looking for ?